# How to set focus to autocomplete contents on inline edit in free jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Free jqgrid first column is Jquery UI autocomplete using custom edit type.
Field is made focusable using `focusField: true`

```
$.extend(true,$.jgrid.inlineEdit, {
    position: "beforeSelected",
    focusField: true,
    keys: true } );
```

If inline editing is started, jqgrid puts focus to autocomplete dropdown button.
How to fix this that focus is put to autocomplete input element ?

Autocomplete button is defined with tabindex=-1:

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-form-dropdown' tabindex=-1 aria-label='Open menu'>
<span class='caret'></span></button>
```

It does not receive focus if tab key is pressed in inline edit.

jqgrid code contains:

```
    getFocusable = function (elem) {
        return $(elem).find("input,textarea,select,button,object,*[tabindex]")
                                            .filter(":input:visible:not(:disabled)");
                                },
```

So jqgrid puts focus  to element even if it contains `tabindex=-1`

How to  fix this ?

Posted also in https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/186

**Update**

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Open page below in Chrome
2. Select row
3. Click in inline edit button

Observed:

Button receives focus

Expected:

input element should receive focus

Code to reproduce:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/css/ui.jqgrid.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var mydata = [
                { id: 0, Name: "Indiana", Category: "IN" },
                { id: 1, Name: "California", Category: "CA" },
                { id: 2, Name: "Pennsylvania", Category: "PA" },
                { id: 3, Name: "Texas", Category: "TX" }
            ];
            var lastSel;
            var grid = $("#list");

            grid.jqGrid({
                data: mydata,
                datatype: 'local',
                colModel: [
                    {
                        name: 'Name', editable: true, width: 200,
                        edittype: 'custom',
                        editoptions: {
                            custom_element: combobox_element,
                            custom_value: function (elem) {
                                return elem.find("input").val();
                            }
                        }
                    },

                { name: 'Category', index: 'Category', width: 50, editable: true }
                ],
                ignoreCase: true,
                gridview: true,
                viewrecords: true,
                rownumbers: true,
                pager: '#pager',
                editurl: 'clientArray',
                ondblClickRow: function (id, ri, ci) {
                    grid.jqGrid('editRow', id, true, null, null, 'clientArray', {});
                },
                onSelectRow: function (id) {
                    if (id && id !== lastSel) {
                        if (typeof lastSel !== "undefined") {
                            grid.jqGrid('restoreRow', lastSel);
                        }
                        lastSel = id;
                    }
                }
            }).
            jqGrid("inlineNav", '#pager');
        });

        var getColumnByName = function (grid, columnName) {
            var cm = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel'), i = 0, l = cm.length;
            for (; i < l; ++i) {
                if (cm[i].name === columnName) {
                    return cm[i];
                }
            }
            return null;
        };

        function combobox_element(value, options) {
            var elemStr = '<div><input class="FormElement', newel, width;
            if (options.id === options.name) {
                elemStr += '" size="' +
                        options.size + '"' + ' id="' + options.id + '"';
            }
            else {
                elemStr += ' form-control jqgrid-inlineedit-autocomplete" ' +
                   ' style="width:' + width + 'px" ' + ' id="' + options.id + '_x"';
            }
            elemStr += ' value="' + value + '" lookup="' + options.lookup + '"/>';
            elemStr += "<button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-form-dropdown' tabindex=-1 aria-label='Open menu'>" +
        "<span class='caret'></span></button>";
            elemStr += '</div>';
            newel = $(elemStr)[0];
            setTimeout(function () {
                input_autocomplete(newel);
            }, 50);
            return newel;
        }

        function input_autocomplete(newel) {
            var input = $("input", newel);
            input.autocomplete({
                source: ["Indiana", 
                "California",
                "Pennsylvania"
                ]
            }
           );
            $("button", newel)
            .bind({
                click: function () {
                    input.focus();
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <table id="list"></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you do exactly. Which part of your code place `<button type='button' ... tabindex=-1 ...`?

Placing of `tabindex=-1` means only that the field should not get focus if the user press Tab or Shift-Tab, but it means that the field should do can be focusable via API call. In other wards, the existence of `tabindex` make it focusable, but the negative value of `tabindex` informs to exclude the element from *sequential focus navigation* only. W3 standard formulate it as (see [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/editing.html#attr-tabindex))

> The user agent must set the element's tabindex focus flag, but should
>   not allow the element to be reached using sequential focus navigation.

One should remove `tabindex` attribute if one don't want to make the button be focusable.

If you don't create the attribute and it does some control which you use, but you still don't want to set the focus on `<button>`, then you can just set the focus on another editable column. You can use `focusField: "someColumnName"` or `focusField: indexOfSomeColumn` to set the focus on specific column.

**UPDATED:** I posted [the fix](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/aacebd1501de9c9c3dc77822b316222a4452ba46) which adds the usage of `.first()` before call of `.focus()`. After the changes the demo which you posted works good.

Comment: I updated question. Focus needs to be set to first column `input` element, so different focusField value cannot specified. Removing tabindex attribute still sets focus to button. Button should clicked only by mouse click or touch. It shoud not focused from focusField or from keyboard.

Comment: @Andrus: What value for `focusField` you use now? Which editing mode you use? Can you provide the demo. which reproduce the problem? The option `focusField: true` means applying the standard setting of the focus to the first focusable element. If you say that free jqGrid have a bug then you should provide the demo with the corresponding test case. If it's not bug, but you need implement your custom logic in setting the focus, then you can use `focusField: true` and set focus manually inside of `oneditfunc` for example.

Comment: `focusField: true` is used for inline editing. Currently if first column contains multiple focusable elements, `focusField: true` can put focus to **any** focusable element in first column. Actually it should put focus to **first** focusable element in first column (using tab order). I can provide demo on request.

Comment: @Andrus: I wrote you already in the previous comment: "Can you provide the demo, which reproduce the problem?" If could be important which version of jQuery you use. It could be that I can fix the problem by including additional `.first()` call in the code. I remind you one common rule: if you think that free jqGrid have a bug you should post the demo which uses non-minimized code `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` from GitHub. After I'll reproduce the bug and post the bug fix the same demo will work correctly.

Comment: Question is updated with testcase and observed, expected behaviours.

Comment: @Andrus: I posted the changes to GitHub. See **UPDATED** part of my question. Th problem should be fixed now.